# Showing tabbar on next screen in Android

Tags: android

Initially I have 3 screens in a tab bar...but when I navigate from any of these activities to any other activity the tab bar disappears...I want this tab bar to appear even on that screen...How to do that??

Answer (score 1):

You could put your tabbar code into a separate XML file (say, `tabbar.xml`) and use

```
<include layout="tabbar" />
```

in each of the layout files.

Then, you would need to set it up in your Activities `onStart` methods.

Comment: i appreciate...i have included it but can you tell me how to implement it in onStart method...i am really stuck here

Comment: You should really get a good book to read the basics. `onStart` is covered here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html